# How to adjust regression for colinearity within certain levels of categorical variable?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, interpretation, multicollinearity

I'm analyzing results from a large workforce survey, with approximately 110,000 responses to each question. We are interested in how certain demographic variables impact employees' opinions, so we construct inverse probability weights to adjust for non-response and then run weighted linear regression on each question.

Most of our independent variables are made to be categorical. Two in particular are: **`age_factor`** and **`length_of_service_factor`**, or how long someone has been in the organization. These two variables aren't in general colinear: `vif()` from the R package [`car`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) gives GVIF of 1.8 for `age_factor` and 2.3 for `length_of_service_factor`.

However, they are apparently correlated for certain, low levels of `age_factor`; clearly an employee who is 24 will not have had a job for more than 10 years! For instance:

- 95% of employees 25 and under have lengths of service of less than 1 year or 1-3 years.
- 75% of employees 26-29 years old have lengths of service of less than 1 year or 1-3 years.

Looking at regression coefficients and least-square means, employees 26-29 expressed dissatisfaction across almost all of the questions. However, the same statistics show that employees with less than 1 or 1-3 years of service responded relatively positively.

So my questions:

- Are there transformations I can make to the predictor variables to remove the colinearity for younger employees?
- As I'm reporting on lower satisfaction for younger employees (`age_factor` of 26-29 years old), how should I adjust for the positive coefficients for newer employees (shorter lengths of service)?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What is your goal in making some kind of adjustment? In other words, so what if there is multicollinearity between the features?

Comment: Thank you Dave! My goal is to be able to accurately explain the results of the model. I'm OK not making any adjustments, so long as there's a clear way of reporting on how younger employees responded.

Comment: Might you combine the`age_factor` and `length_of_service_factor` into a single categorical predictor? My guess is that you don't have many 60-65-year-olds with less than 1 year of service, either. That would be like examining the interaction between `age_factor` and `length_of_service_factor` (which seems important to evaluate at first glance) while omitting combinations that don't happen in practice.